# Auto Authentication in Embedded link (AWS Opensearch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, kibana, elk, opensearch-dashboards

I have hosted AWS OpenSearch(ELK) and with that Kibana also get hosted. So I have created a dashboard in Kibana where I get the embedded link and insert it to my HTML code. It ask me to login Everytime.
If I host a EC2 instance and install Nginx in it and is it possible if I configure Nginx.conf and provided the access credentials to it so whenever my website gets loaded Visualization inserted in my website through Kibana Embedded Link it should not ask for authentication.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.